# BUILD FAILED in netbeans 8.02 - compilation failure - build-impl.xml

Tags: java, ant, netbeans-8, struts-1

When trying to compile my application I get the following error:

```
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
Created dir: D:\CCSingleView\build\empty
Created dir: D:\CCSingleView\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 271 source files to D:\CCSingleView\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
                Map ENF_FUNCTION_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENF_FUNCTION_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
                Map DATA_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("DATA_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
                Map ENF_FUNCTION_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENF_FUNCTION_TYPE","");
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,String)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
                Map DATA_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("DATA_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
                Map EFI_PARAM_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("EFI_PARAM_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
                Map ENF_FUNCTION_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENF_FUNCTION_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
                Map DATA_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("DATA_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
                Map EFI_PARAM_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("EFI_PARAM_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
                    ArrayList templateList = importDAO.getTemplateList1(fspId, callFrom, folderID);
  symbol:   method getTemplateList1(String,String,String)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
                    Map ENF_FUNCTION_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENF_FUNCTION_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
                    Map ENF_ENRICH_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENF_ENRICH_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
                    Map impModes = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("IMPORT_MODE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
                    Map enrlkupMatch = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENR_LOOKUP_MATCHES", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:144: error: cannot find symbol
                    Map ENR_SPLIT_ACTION = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENR_SPLIT_ACTION", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:173: error: cannot find symbol
                    Map ENF_ENRICH_TYPE = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENF_ENRICH_TYPE", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:228: error: cannot find symbol
                Map ENR_SPLIT_ACTION = importbo.getLookUpMapStatic("ENR_SPLIT_ACTION", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importbo of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:230: error: cannot find symbol
                Map enrlkupMatch = importbo.getLookUpMapStatic("ENR_LOOKUP_MATCHES", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importbo of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:698: error: cannot find symbol
                Map enr_exec_modes = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENR_EXEC_MODES", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:702: error: cannot find symbol
                Map enr_exec_modes = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENR_EXEC_MODES", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:706: error: cannot find symbol
                Map execution_flag = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("EXECUTION_FLAG", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Enrich\EnrichFunction.java:777: error: cannot find symbol
                Map enr_exec_modes = importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic("ENR_EXEC_MODES", null);
  symbol:   method getLookUpMapStatic(String,<null>)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Importer\AddImport.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
            ArrayList importModes = importDAO.getLookUpListStat("IMPORT_MODE", "");//static
  symbol:   method getLookUpListStat(String,String)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Importer\AddImport.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
            importDAO.closeSession();
  symbol:   method closeSession()
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Importer\EditImport.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
             String ref=uploadForm.getRefreshFileChecked();
  symbol:   method getRefreshFileChecked()
  location: variable uploadForm of type EditUploadForm
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Importer\EditImport.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            if (uploadForm.getRefreshFileChecked() == null) {
  symbol:   method getRefreshFileChecked()
  location: variable uploadForm of type EditUploadForm
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Importer\ImportAction.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
            ArrayList delimeterList = importDAO.getLookUpListStat("IMP_DELIMITER", "");
  symbol:   method getLookUpListStat(String,String)
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\action\Importer\ImportAction.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
            importDAO.closeSession();
  symbol:   method closeSession()
  location: variable importDAO of type ImportDAO
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
            sql = QueryConstant.getQuery(lookUpName, mcmImtImdId);
  symbol:   method getQuery(String,String)
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
                if (row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1) != null && row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2) != null) {
  symbol:   variable columnValue1
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
                if (row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1) != null && row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2) != null) {
  symbol:   variable columnValue2
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
                    lookUpList.put(row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1).toString(), row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2).toString());
  symbol:   variable columnValue1
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:54: error: cannot find symbol



    lookUpList.put(row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1).toString(), row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2).toString());
  symbol:   variable columnValue2
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
                    lookUpList.put((String) row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1), (String) row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2));
  symbol:   variable columnValue1
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
                    lookUpList.put((String) row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1), (String) row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2));
  symbol:   variable columnValue2
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
                sqlTemp = QueryConstant.getQueryForList("APPEND_COLUMNS1", tableName);
  symbol:   method getQueryForList(String,String)
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
                sqlTemp = QueryConstant.getQueryForList(lookUpName, tableName);
  symbol:   method getQueryForList(String,String)
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
                if (row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1) != null) {
  symbol:   variable columnValue1
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
                    lkb.setLookUpCode(row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1).toString());
  symbol:   variable columnValue1
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
                    lkb.setLookUpCode((String) row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue1));
  symbol:   variable columnValue1
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
                if (row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2) != null) {
  symbol:   variable columnValue2
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
                    lkb.setLookUpMeaning(row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2).toString());
  symbol:   variable columnValue2
  location: class QueryConstant
D:\CCSingleView\src\java\com\cc\dedup\applicationsetup\dao\UtlLookUp.java:126: error: cannot find symbol
                    lkb.setLookUpMeaning((String) row.get(QueryConstant.columnValue2));
  symbol:   variable columnValue2
  location: class QueryConstant
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
42 errors
D:\CCSingleView\nbproject\build-impl.xml:903: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\CCSingleView\nbproject\build-impl.xml:324: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

**and line where i am getting issue is**

```
build-impl.xml:903:`<webproject2:javac destdir="${build.classes.dir}" gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>`

build-impl.xml:324: `<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}">`
```

Comment: i am not able to build my application but able to run my application.

Comment: You have an error in `EnrichFunction.java` it references a method that does not exist . `importDAO.getLookUpMapStatic()` There is nothing we can do without seeing the sources. This has nothing to do with NetBeans or the build script it uses

Comment: Hi , Thank you for reply.  where evere i am getting error here(cannot find symbol) , there we have those methods and those methods and classes are working perfectly. i am able to run my application.  here is one of my class.

Comment: finally i am able to  build my project successfully. what i did was  moved those java classes in to another folder which will compile before the current classes. so now build is ok, but not able to generate war and not able to open the application on browser. so through run i am generating a war .but issues with war . few class files missing in it...  any idea on this @a_horse_with_no_name